# Identifying the centre of a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

I've been asked to identify with reasons of properties of circles , the centre of the circle which passes through

Q1 . A, D and E

Q2. A, C, And E .

I'm not too sure how to approach this question

Comment: I would say that the approach is to answer what little questions you can answer. For example, perhaps ask yourself: can you calculate numerical values of some of the other angles? Work from there, asking and answering more questions, building up more and more information. Hopefully eventually you will have so much information that you can answer Q1 and Q2.

Comment: Start by finding angle ACB, hence angle CAB, hence angle DAE. That should allow you to solve Q1.

Answer (score 0):

Like Lee Mosher hinted, finding the angles will help you solve both questions. I'll provide a couple of hints which should hopefully give you an idea on how to approach both questions.

$FA = FC$ since they're both tangents drawn from $F$ to the circle.

$\implies \angle FCA = \angle FAC \implies \angle BAC = 26^o \implies \angle DAE = 90^o$. (This is should be enough to solve Q1)

Another hint: Join $B$ to $D$ and compare $\angle ADB$ and $\angle ACB$, and $\angle CAB$ and $\angle CDB$.